# How to retrieve object name from argument passed into helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very simple Rails question:

I am passing an argument to a helper function from within a view, like this:

```
<%= function(@project.date) %>
```

How can I use the instance variable `@project` within that helper function?

```
def function(date)
  date.object_name?
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you need the `@project` variable inside `function`, just pass it as argumente instead of `@project.date`.

Comment: OK, I think the problem is that I need to pass both, the variable `@project` **and** an attribute (which could also be another one than `date`). So I will have to pass them separately, like this: `function(@project, @project.date)`?

Comment: Yes, if you like you could define `function` like this: `def function(project, date=project.date)`, so you don't need to pass the `date` argument explicitly when it is equal to `@project.date`.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like in comment.

Use it for example like that

```
<%= function(@project, @project.date) %>

def function(object, date)
   date if object.class == String
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I knew that though ;-) But what if I need to pass an instance variable **plus** an attribute?

Comment: So pass two arguments, don't know why but if you really need that you can do that :)